# Tikz - Help with geometric construction from photo

Tags: tikz-pgf, teaching

I would like to make "cheat sheet" for my students, but I'm not goot with Tikz. I would like to recreate 11 geometric constructions in pictures I added. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

[image: First page]

[image: Second page]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! "Not good with Ti*k*Z" implies (to my understanding) that you know Ti*k*Z at least basically. So, it would be nice to see what you tried so far! There are lot of instructions on the web (and also on this site) where you should be able to find some ideas regarding how to start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a `tkz-euclide` and some notions about style in `TikZ`

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{3/1/A,2/4/B}
\tkzDefLine[mediator](A,B) \tkzGetPoints{C}{D}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\tkzDrawLine(C,D)
\tkzDrawCircle[diameter](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{I}
\foreach \p in {,0,0.2,...,1}
{\tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=\p](C,D) \tkzGetPoint{K}
\tkzDrawPoint(K)
\tkzDrawCircle(K,A)
\tkzCompasss[delta=10,color=red, thick](A,K B,K) }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,-4/0/B,4/0/A}
  \tkzDrawSemiCircle(O,A)
  \tkzDrawSegment(A,B)
  \foreach \i/\an in  {1/30,2/60,3/90,4/120,5/150}{%
  \tkzDefPoint(\an:4){C\i} 
  \tkzDrawSegments({B,C\i} {C\i,A})
  \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,C\i,A)
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,4/0/A}
    \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
    \foreach \i/\a in {1/0,2/72,3/144,4/216,5/288} {%
    \tkzDefPoint(\a:4){c_\i}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R](c_\i,4)
    \tkzDrawPoint[color=red,shape=cross out,size=12pt](c_\i)}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

using tikz is not that difficult, don't be afraid of this mountain of documentation. Try.
A small example to show you that the code is readable

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[red] (0,0) circle (3cm);
\draw (-3,0) coordinate(A) node[left]{A} --(3,0)coordinate(B)node[right]{B};
\foreach \aa in {18,30,65, 125,150,195,260,-35,290}
    {\draw (A) -- ({3*cos(\aa)},{3*sin(\aa)}) -- (B);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]